# Compile watchman failed with "invalid syntax"

Tags: python, syntax-error, watchman

I'm trying to create a docker container that contains watchman, but unfortunately, the compile fails in a very early stage with the following message:

```
Step 8/13 : RUN cd /tmp  && git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git watchman --depth 1 -b ${WATCHMAN_TAG}
 ---> Running in b3b97816dc40
Cloning into 'watchman'...
Note: checking out '9312386414e1d0309f4ee815b70cef461b846c00'.                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Removing intermediate container b3b97816dc40                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 ---> fddd6f6c7324
Step 9/13 : RUN cd /tmp/watchman  && ./autogen.sh  && ./configure  && make  && make install  && cd $HOME  && rm -rf /tmp/*
 ---> Running in e37d2af112e7
+ PREFIX=/usr/local
+ python3 build/fbcode_builder/getdeps.py build --src-dir=. watchman --project-install-prefix=watchman:/usr/local                                                                                                                                                                           
  File "build/fbcode_builder/getdeps.py", line 578                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    f"Will reconfigure cmake because {dep_file} is newer than {built_marker}"                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                            ^                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

WATCHMAN_TAG is "v2021.03.22.00" and I python-dev (also tried python3-dev package) are also installed:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y automake autoconf build-essential libtool libssl-dev pkg-config python3-dev
```

Does anyone knows how how I can sovle the issue?

Comment: f strings are a python 3.6 syntax, presumably watchman is using a python version less than that

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the problem. I was using python 3.5.3 - which was too old.